# Tidyr separate returns error "_tidyr_simplifyPieces"

Tags: r, tidyr

Using Tidyr separate to split one column into two returns the following error:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b', 'b|c', 'x|y'))

tidyr::separate(data = df, col = FOO, into = c("left", "right"), sep = 
"\\|")
```

> Error in simplifyPieces(pieces, n, fill == "left") : 
>   object '_tidyr_simplifyPieces' not found

Any suggestions on why this is occurring?

```
Session Info:

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zeallot_0.1.0              fANCOVA_0.5-1              survival_2.42-3           
 [4] lubridate_1.7.4            lmPerm_2.1.0               gridExtra_2.3             
 [7] PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2 xts_0.10-2                 RColorBrewer_1.1-2        
[10] kableExtra_0.9.0           zoo_1.8-1                  caTools_1.17.1            
[13] randomForest_4.6-14        scales_1.0.0               factoextra_1.0.5          
[16] ggplot2_3.0.0              psych_1.8.4                data.table_1.11.2         
[19] reshape2_1.4.3             car_3.0-0                  carData_3.0-1             
[22] raster_2.6-7               sp_1.2-7                   dplyr_0.7.5               
[25] tidyr_0.8.1
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue with `0.8.1` tidyr

Comment: Strange, I am also running 0.8.1

Comment: Can you please check on a new session

Comment: Restarting RStudio resolved the issue. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I detached plyr and reran the code, and it works now. It's quite a common problem when plyr is loaded after dplyr.